# Dynamic Skin Change in DataGrid, Flex 3

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I'm trying to dynamically change the sortArrowSkin in a DataGrid.

Here's my code:

```
grid.clearStyle("sortArrowSkin");
grid.setStyle("sortArrowSkin", mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin);
```

and then resetting it later with

```
grid.clearStyle("sortArrowSkin");
grid.setStyle("sortArrowSkin", mx.skins.halo.DataGridSortArrow);
```

The output of getStyle("sortArrowSkin") is the correct value after each of these, but the sort arrow remains in the header.

If I set either of these statically at the start they work fine, but if I change them dynamically like this, the change is not reflected.

I've also tried to invalidate all of the grid's properties, displaylist, size, etc. after setting the style, but with the same results.

Has anyone been able to do this successfully?